# Golang - How does golang memory profile count allocs/op?

Tags: json, go, memory, memory-management, marshalling

I'm writing a custom JSON marshal function and comparing it to the built-in `json.Marshal` method.

My understanding is that when `bytes.Buffer` reaches its capacity, it needs to double its size and this costs 1 allocation.

However, benchmark result seems to indicate `json.Marshal` is doing this in a way where it does NOT need to allocate whenever it grows the underlying buffer, whereas my implementation seems to cost an extra allocation everytime the buffer doubles.

Why would `MarshalCustom` (code below) need to allocate more than `json.Marshal`?

```
$ go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^BenchmarkMarshalText$ test
BenchmarkMarshalText/Marshal_JSON-10               79623             13545 ns/op            3123 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkMarshalText/Marshal_Custom-10        142296              8378 ns/op           12464 B/op          8 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test    2.356s
```

Full code.

```golang
type fakeStruct struct {
    Names []string `json:"names"`
}

var ResultBytes []byte

func BenchmarkMarshalText(b *testing.B) {
    names := randomNames(1000)

    b.Run("Marshal JSON", func(b *testing.B) {
        fs := fakeStruct{
            Names: names,
        }

        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            ResultBytes, _ = json.Marshal(fs)
        }
    })

    b.Run("Marshal Custom", func(b *testing.B) {
        fs := fakeStruct{
            Names: names,
        }

        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            ResultBytes = MarshalCustom(fs)
        }
    })
}

func MarshalCustom(fs fakeStruct) []byte {
    var b bytes.Buffer

    b.WriteByte('{')

    // Names
    b.WriteString(`,"names":[`)
    for i := 0; i < len(fs.Names); i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            b.WriteByte(',')
        }
        b.WriteByte('"')
        b.WriteString(fs.Names[i])
        b.WriteByte('"')
    }
    b.WriteByte(']')

    b.WriteByte('}')

    buf := append([]byte(nil), b.Bytes()...)
    return buf
}

func randomNames(num int) []string {
    const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    const maxLen = 5

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    res := make([]string, rand.Intn(num))
    for i := range res {
        l := rand.Intn(maxLen) + 1 // cannot be empty
        s := make([]byte, l)
        for j := range s {
            s[j] = letters[rand.Intn(len(letters))]
        }
        res[i] = string(s)
    }

    return res
}
```

Comment: Because json library has this handy pool in it: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/encoding/json/encode.go;drc=2580d0e08d5e9f979b943758d3c49877fb2324cb;l=302

Comment: @oakad you're right. `json.Marshal` does not need to allocate everytime because it is resuing buffers from the `sync.pool`

Answer (score 0):

@oakad is correct. If I force a GC run in every iteration of the benchmark, the allocs/op is much closer or even the same.

```golang
for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    // marshal here

    runtime.GC()
}
```